# Группировка (оптимизация) классов и стилей CSS на выходе из WebPack 4?

Tags: webpack

Собираю проект через webpack 4 и на выходе получаю "полу-оптимизированный" css.

**Выдержка из webpack.config.js:**

```
{
    test: /\.((s[ac]|c)ss)$/,
    use: [
        PLUGINS.mini_css_extract_plugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction
            }
        },

        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
                plugins: (() => {
                    return isProduction ? [
                        require('autoprefixer')({
                            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
                        }),
                        require('cssnano')({
                            preset: 'default'
                        }),
                        require("css-mqpacker")
                    ] : []
                })()
            }
        },

        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: !isProduction
            }
        },
    ]
},
```

**1. Перед сборкой проекта имею следующий scss код:**

```
.class_1 {
    width: 1px;
}

.class_2 {
    width: 1px;
}

.class_3 {
    width: 2px;
}
```

**2. После сборки на выходе имею следующее:**

```
.class_1, .class_2 {
    width: 1px
}

.class_3 {
    width: 2px
}
```

Вроде бы все замечательно и оптимизация классов произошла, НО! Пробуем изменить последовательность классов в scss и запустить сборку заново...

**3. Перед сборкой проекта имею следующий scss код (поменял местами class_2  и class_3):**

```
.class_1 {
    width: 1px;
}

.class_3 {
    width: 2px;
}

.class_2 {
    width: 1px;
}
```

**4. После сборки на выходе имею следующее:**

```
.class_1 {
    width: 1px
}

.class_3 {
    width: 2px
}

.class_2 {
    width: 1px
}
```

Хотелось бы оптимизировать все классы, а не только те, которые идут исключительно друг за другом.

Подскажите плагин (и его настройки), чтобы объединять названия классов, если у них одинаковые стили?

## UPD:

В связи с тем, что многих будоражит `width: 2px;` - заменим его на `color: red;`

**На входе:**

```
.class_1 {
    width: 1px;
}

.class_3 {
    color: red;
}

.class_2 {
    width: 1px;
}
```

**На выходе:**

```
.class_1 {
    width: 1px
}

.class_3 {
    color: red
}

.class_2 {
    width: 1px
}
```

Comment: Эта оптимизация невозможна - она изменит поведение для `<div class="class_2 class_3">`

Comment: Понял Вашу мысль, дополнил вопрос...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение задачи: [PostCSS Merge Selectors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-merge-selectors).

Не без проблем, но задачу решает...